# Stack bootstrap buttons properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button

So I was making my personal website, and decided to add resume view (google drive link) and resume download option. So I added buttons, and attached glyphicons to them, and used some custom css to make them fit with the find easter eggs button.
I coded on my PC and was happy with the results, but I suddenly remembered that phones might not handle it properly and I was right. 
[image: Download and View Buttons appear accurately]
^ This is ok

[image: On phone they aren't stacking and look rather odd]

^ This I need to fix but can't understand how.

Code for the header:

```
  <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="intro-text">
                <div class="intro-lead-in">Hey There!</div>
                <div class="intro-heading">It's Nice To Meet You</div>
                <div class="btn-group"></div>
                <a href="#services" class="page-scroll btn btn-xl ">Find easter eggs</a>
                    <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl"> -->

                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary padbtn" id='vr'>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>&nbsp;
</button>

<!-- ISSUE HERE!! -->

                        <!-- <i class="fa fa-at fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i> -->

                    <a download="Resume_Ayush_Mandowara.pdf" href="\pdf\RESUME_14_6_17.pdf"><button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary padbtn" id='dr'>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-download"></span>&nbsp;
    </button></a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

CSS applied to download and view buttons:

```
.padbtn
{
    padding: 1.1em;
}
```

I want to stick the view and download buttons together, and make it look not so horrible, any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Seems like you didn't include some CSS. Your code doesn't replicate the screenshot. https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/LLRBzB

Comment: Looks like you are not using the button group correctly. <div class="btn-group"></div>. The closing div should be after the buttons

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Bootstrap you could use the column classes but this appears to be more of a one off and the columns might not provide the spacing/layout you're looking for.

I would wrap the two buttons that you want grouped in another element. Then add a media query to switch between inline and block display. Setting the grouping element to `display: block;` will move it below the Easter Egg button.

Here's a simplified example.

```css
.my-btns {
  text-align: center;
}

@media ( min-width: 481px ) {
  .my-btn-group {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="my-btns">
  <button>Easter Eggs</button>
  <div class="my-btn-group">
    <button>1</button>
    <button>2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```